# How can I add numbers into this pictures to get maximize the number of regions for a give number of lines automatically?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to number region of lines dividing a plane line this picture.
[image]

With one line, we have two regions, with two lines, we have four regions. I tried

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
    (0,0) coordinate (O)
    (-2,-2) coordinate (A)
    (2,2) coordinate (B)
    (2,-2) coordinate (C)
    (-2,2) coordinate (D);
    \node at (barycentric cs:A=1,C=1,B=1) {$1$};
    \node at (barycentric cs:A=1,D=1,B=1) {$2$};
    \draw (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
    (0,0) coordinate (O)
    (-2,-2) coordinate (A)
    (2,2) coordinate (B)
    (-4,-2) coordinate (C)
    (4,2) coordinate (D);
    \draw (A) -- (B) (C) -- (D);
    \node at (barycentric cs:A=1,O=1,C=1) {$1$};
    \node at (barycentric cs:B=1,O=1,C=1) {$2$};
    \node at (barycentric cs:B=1,O=1,D=1) {$3$};
    \node at (barycentric cs:A=1,O=1,D=1) {$4$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

I know that, the maximum number $ L_n $ is $ \dfrac{n^2+n+2}{2} $. How can I draw the above this picture automatically How can  I add numbers  into this pictures automatically?

Comment: To be automatic, a rule is needed. Pls describe the rule!

Comment: @BlackMild Rule is  $ L_n=\dfrac{n^2+n+2}{2} $. Please read question carefully.

Comment: I suspect that the best location for the label is the incenter, that is, the center of a circle inscribed inside the triangle.  It is located at the intersection of two (or more) of the vertex angle bisectors.  One should be able to calculate it algebraically from the vertex coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is far from a complete answer. The question seems to be how, given the number `n` of lines, one may arrange them that the number of regions attains its maximal number, `(n^2+n+2)/2`. I think that the following conditions are necessary:

1. No two different lines are parallel.
2. No more than two lines intersect in a given intersection point.

Using these guidelines, one can construct a pic that creates such an arrangement.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/divi/.style={code={
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {360*\X/(#1+1-isodd(#1))}]
     in {1,...,#1}
\draw[scale=1/#1] ({90+\Y}:#1/4)
++ ({180+\Y}:1+1.5*#1) -- ++ ({\Y}:2+3*#1);
}}]
\matrix {\pic {divi=1}; & \pic {divi=2}; \\
\pic {divi=3}; & \pic {divi=4}; \\
\pic {divi=5}; & \pic {divi=6}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have not even tried to put the numbers in.

Comment: I hope, you add numbers.

Comment: Labelling numbers $L_n$ is simple: add `local bounding box` in SC's `pic` code. However, labelling all numbers $1,2,...,L_n$ is time-consuming job, even with the rule of barrycentric center due to a lot of calculation coordinates of vertexes.

Comment: ``\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/divi/.style={code={
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=L#1]
\foreach \X[evaluate=\X as \Y using {360*\X/(#1+1-isodd(#1))}]
     in {1,...,#1}
\draw[scale=1/#1] ({90+\Y}:#1/4)
++ ({180+\Y}:1+1.5*#1)--++({\Y}:2+3*#1);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{#1} \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ln}{int((\n*\n+\n+2)/2)} 
\path (L#1.south) node[below]{$L_{\n}=\Ln$};
\end{scope}
}}]
\matrix{
\pic{divi=1};&\pic{divi=2};\\
\pic{divi=3};&\pic{divi=4};\\
\pic{divi=5};&\pic{divi=6};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}``

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

This provides a macro to compute the incenter for a triangle.  The hard part was avoiding floating point overflows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\incenter}[4]% #1-#3 = coordinate names for vertices, #4 = name of incenter
{\pgfscope
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xa}{\ya}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xc}{\yc}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{veclen(\xc-\xb,\yc-\yb)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{veclen(\xc-\xa,\yc-\ya)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{veclen(\xb-\xa,\yb-\ya)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{\a+\b+\c}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\a/\d}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\b/\d}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{\c/\d}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xo}{\a*\xa + \b*\xb + \c*\xc}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\yo}{\a*\ya + \b*\yb + \c*\yc}%
  \pgfcoordinate{#4}{\pgfpoint{\xo}{\yo}}
\endpgfscope}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
    (0,0) coordinate (O)
    (-2,-2) coordinate (A)
    (2,2) coordinate (B)
    (2,-2) coordinate (C)
    (-2,2) coordinate (D);
    \draw (A) -- (B);
    \incenter{A}{C}{B}{O1}%
    \node at (O1) {1};
    \incenter{A}{D}{B}{O2}%
    \node at (O2) {2};
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
    (0,0) coordinate (O)
    (-2,-2) coordinate (A)
    (2,2) coordinate (B)
    (-4,-2) coordinate (C)
    (4,2) coordinate (D);
    \draw (A) -- (B) (C) -- (D);
    \incenter{A}{O}{C}{O1}%
    \node at (O1) {1};
    \incenter{B}{O}{C}{O2}%
    \node at (O2) {2};
    \incenter{B}{O}{D}{O3}%
    \node at (O3) {3};
    \incenter{A}{O}{D}{O4}%
    \node at (O4) {4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

[image: geometry lesson]

Comment: centroid (can be get via barrycentric cs) is more suitable than incenter, as in case $L_3=7$. However, I think an general algorithm is hard or not-enough-motivative to make due to a lot of coordinate of intersection points, and automatic size of labels. Manual labeling is a way.

Answer (score 3):

Drawing these diagrams is easy. The code below defines a macro, `\DividedPlanes`, so that

```
  \DividedPlanes{5}
  \DividedPlanes{6}
```

produces these configurations for 5 and 6 points, respectively:

[image]

The lines in `\DividedPlanes{<n>}` are drawn by first using a `\foreach` loop to place `n` coordinates around a circle of radius `2` at the points `2k\pi/n`, for `k=1,2,...,n`. After this, the lines are drawn by looping over all pairs of numbers (equivalently, points), in `{1,2,...,n}`. With more thought than I have time for at the moment (it's a work day), it should be possible to label the regions (the behaviour is slightly different when `n` is odd and when it is even). I may come back to this if the local feline population does not beat me to it.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% allow an optional argument so that we can pass some optional
% style commands to the tikzpicture environment
% usage: \DividedPlanes[style]{n}
\newcommand\DividedPlanes[2][]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    % reserve some real estate for the image
    \draw[white](-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    \foreach \pt  in {1,...,#2} {
        % name coordinates (1), (2), ..., (#2)
        \coordinate (\pt) at (\pt*360/#2:2);
    }
    \foreach \apt in {1,...,#2} {
       \foreach \bpt in {1,...,#2} {
         \ifnum\apt=\bpt\else
           % draw a line when a and b are distinct
           \draw[shorten >=-20,shorten <=-20](\apt)--(\bpt);
         \fi
       }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

  \DividedPlanes{2}

  \DividedPlanes{3}
  \DividedPlanes{4}

  \DividedPlanes{5}
  \DividedPlanes{6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am just a member of the feline population but if the aim is that you want to maximize the number of regions for a give number of lines, I do not think you should allow more than two lines in a point. Rather, according to what I think the rules include that (i) no two lines are parallel and (ii) no more than two lines intersect in a point.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes, I want to maximize the number of regions for a give number of lines.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen If the only rule is adding $L_n$ then just insert `\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{int(#2-1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ln}{int((\n*\n+\n+2)/2)}
\path (current bounding box.south) node[below]{$L_{\n}=\Ln$};` right before `\end{tikzpicture}` in the above Andrew's code.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for the explanation. I see I misunderstood the problem (but perhaps not the solution given your answer +1 :)